# Error validating application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When trying to make a post on my wall (using the ruby gem fb_graph) I get an "Error validating application" message. I've been scouring google for solutions but to no avail. Any idea on how I should start debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

"*Any idea on how I should start debugging this?*"

Start by taking the access token and ensuring it validates well: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

and ensure it has the required permissions for posting to walls: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: when I input it into the debug tool, all it says is "Error validating application" with no other info. Doesn't exactly tell me much I don't already know :/

Comment: Did you try debugging your secret key?  Or an access token?

Comment: I saw it, but you might want to ensure you're getting the user access token and not an app access token.  Best way to tell what type of access token you have is to check it in the linter tool.  You can go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ and take one of those tokens.